# Select columns of temporary table

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

For a table created as following how could we select the columns so that we can loop through the columns in a PLSQL.

```
 CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE temptable
    ( column1 datatype [ NULL | NOT NULL ],
      column2 datatype [ NULL | NOT NULL ],
      ...
      column_n datatype [ NULL | NOT NULL ]
    );
```

Some thing like following but for a temporary table.

```
  SELECT *
  FROM all_tab_cols
 where table_name = 'temptable'
   and user = 'user'
```

Answer (score 2):

Temporary table columns are stored in ALL_TAB_COLUMNS too.

```
SQL> select  t.table_name, c.column_name, c.data_type
  2  from all_tables t
  3       join all_tab_cols c
  4      on c.table_name = t.table_name
  5  where t.temporary = 'Y'
  6  and t.owner = user
  7  order by c.column_id; 

TABLE_NAME COLUMN_NAM DATA_TYPE
---------- ---------- ----------
GTT1       COL1       VARCHAR2
GTT1       COL2       NUMBER
GTT1       COL3       VARCHAR2

SQL>
```

> "I already tried this , may be its not there because i am checking it in another stored procedure "

It seems unlikely that would make a difference. What does make a difference is *case*. I notice your posted query uses lower case: `where table_name = 'temptable'` . Try `where table_name = upper('temptable')` and see whether that helps.

Comment: I already tried this , may be its not there because i am checking it in another stored procedure , I passed the temp table name in a procedure where i am checking all this.